# Service object wrongly typed for angular directive in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, directive

Below is typescript for an angular directive.  The problem is with the injected service "datacontext".  The debugger shows that the datacontext in the constructor is a WINDOW object, not the datacontext object that was created as a service.  Therefore, in the scope.viewRecord function, the datacontext.cancelChanges() function is, obviously, undefined - - as its not part of a WINDOW object  This is probably some strange scoping issue that I just don't get, but I'm at a loss as to how to debug this.  Any insight would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

```
module app {
    export interface IEditButtonGroup {
        ...
    }

    export interface IEditButtonScope extends ng.IScope {
        ...
    }

    export class PrxEditButtonGroup implements IEditButtonGroup {
        public static $inject: Array<string> = [
            "datacontext"
        ];
        constructor(
            public datacontext: IDataContext, <---- datacontext HERE is typed as a WINDOW object
            public directive: ng.IDirective = {}) {
            directive.templateUrl = "app/directives/templates/editbuttongroup.html",
            directive.restrict = 'E';
            directive.link = (scope: IEditButtonScope, element, attr) => {
                scope.isEditing = false;
                scope.isAdding = false;

                $("form.disabled").find("input:not(:disabled), select:not(:disabled), textarea:not(:disabled)").prop("disabled", true);

                scope.editRecord = () => {
                    $("input, select, textarea").removeAttr("disabled");
                    scope.isEditing = true;
                    scope.afterEdit();
                }

                scope.viewRecord = (afterCancel: boolean) => {
                    datacontext.cancelChanges(); <--- HERE TOO!  Debugger says datacontext = WINDOW object
                    scope.isEditing = scope.isAdding = false;
                    $("form.disabled").find("input:not(:disabled), select:not(:disabled), textarea:not(:disabled)").prop("disabled", true);
                    scope.afterAdd();
                }
            }
            return <any>directive;
        }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be at the place where you register this directive. Make sure it is like :

```
mymodule.directive('prxEditButtonGroup',app.PrxEditButtonGroup )
```

Comment: Indeed it is!  Somehow app.directive('prxEditButtonGroup', ['$window', prxEditButtonGroup]) snuck in there.  Probably left over from before I converted the directive to Typescript.  You're the man, basarat.